# Magento customer login with SHA1 password encryption

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have upload Customer with `sha1()` password encryption. But I think that Magento uses MD5 for password hashing. The problem is that we have already uploaded 100,000 customers - now they can not login. Is there a way to convert these `sha1()` passwords to MD5 *or* change the logic of Magento to use with `sha1()` rather than MD5?

Comment: Those are not passwords, those are hash values of the password, so there is no way to do any kind of conversion

Comment: is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To validate a customer password, it uses `validatePassword` function of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class.

If we trace this function then it calls `validateHash` function of `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` class. And again it calls `validateHash` function of `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` class to validate hash.

Here it calls `hash` function of `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` class and it returns `md5` encrypted data.

So here you can temporary change `md5` with `sha1` and check either it works or not.

Comment: @Bhavesh  post your answer so someone can benefit